# PHP convert date

Tags: php, date

I am trying to convert a date into a different format, but when I do I always get 1970-01-01.  Below is a copy of my code.

```
 $courseDate = $_SESSION['get_course_date']; //value returns '17/03/2014 - Standard Course'
 $regex='((?:(?:[0-2]?\\d{1})|(?:[3][01]{1}))[-:\\/.](?:[0]?[1-9]|[1][012])[-:\\/.](?:(?:[1]{1}\\d{1}\\d{1}\\d{1})|(?:[2]{1}\\d{3})))(?![\\d])'; 
 if ($c=preg_match_all ("/".$regex."/is", $courseDate, $matches)){ //use regex to get just he date
   $get_date=$matches[1][0]; // returns 17/3/2014
   echo date('Y-m-d', $get_date); // output 1970-01-01
 }
```

Any feedback would be great.

Cheers

Comment: your doing it the hard way, see related >>

Comment: what format do you want to achieve?

Comment: 1970-01-01 is the epoch date. Something is setting your timestamp to 0

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is due to `date()` requiring a unix timestamp as its second parameter. You are giving it a date string. You can use `strtotime()` to convert your date to a unix timestamp. We also have to use `str_replace()` to change the slashes to dashes. This is due to `strtotime()` defaulting to US format when it sees the `/` separator. By changing it to a dash it defaults to European format:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $get_date)));
```

Here's an alternative solution that should be easier to manage:

```
$string = '17/03/2014 - Standard Course';
list($date) = explode(' - ', $string);
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date);
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d');
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/9asM6V)